# How to create Android Appcelerator custom module after ADT support is withdrawn by Google?

Tags: android, module, titanium, appcelerator, adt

Android Custom modules i have created with Titanium SDK 5.4.0.GA is not working with latest SDK 6.X.X So trying to rebuild with latest SDK.

But i see ADT is not available now. I'm not able to build custom module with out ADT,  getting below errors

> The import android.app.Activity cannot be resolved

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_Development_Tools

Above Appcelerator link still says to setup ADT.

is there any other way to create custom module without ADT ?

Comment: Nowadays we use Android Studio... ADT has been gone for I guess two years now, maybe a bit less - or more, I'm not entirely sure, it has been some time though.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Can you please tel me How to use Android Studio with Appcelerator Studio for ADT. I want to create new Custom module and build it with latest Appcelerator IDE

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this documentation on how to build modules: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Upgrade_Guide

If you module just needs to be recompiled you can use `appc ti build -p android -b` in your terminal to rebuild your module without using Appc Studio.